# Raspberry Pi Radio Transmitter Error

Tags: python, audio, permissions, raspberry-pi

I have read that the Raspberry Pi is capable of transmitting FM.
I have downloaded the script and put on the directory "/home/pi/".
Then I have executed following commands in the terminal over putty:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PiFm
>>> PiFm.play_sound("left_right.wav")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "PiFm.py", line 7, in play_sound
call(["./pifm", filename])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have ensured that the soundfile "left_right.wav" is in the same directory.
I don't know why this error is throwed.

I use Raspbian as OS, if this is revelant...

EDIT: The files used are in this download: http://cdn.makezine.com/make/pifm/PiRadio.zip